# Where is the method that creates the Reversal Lines in PMTran from the AR Release process?

Tags: acumatica

I have a question regarding the AR Invoice Release of an Invoice that is associated to a Project.  I'm Trying to find the BLC Method in the ARReleaseProcess (or possibly elsewhere) code where the Project Transaction lines are created from an Allocation Rule where the Reverse Allocation is set to On AR Invoice Release.

Essentially trying to find the method that creates the Reversal Lines in PMTran.

Thanks much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Stack Trace of the SQL log for the PMTran insert, I can tell that the Reverse Transaction is actually posted from the Journal Entry created by the Invoice Release and not by the Invoice Release.

[image]

The `PX.Objects.GL.PostGraph` that contains the posting logic has an extension point related to the Project Module.

```
// PX.Objects.GL.PostGraph
/// <summary>
/// Extension point to create project transaction
/// </summary>
protected virtual void CreateProjectTransactions(Batch b)
{
}
```

There is an extension of it in the `PX.Objects.PM` library called `PostGraphExt` that overrides the `CreateProjectTranscations` method. I assume this is the spot you are looking for.
[image]